# Unity3D produces unreadable log when building Windows Store application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

I have following environment:
PC with Windows 10 x64, Russian GUI.
Unity3D 5.2.1p2 x64
Visual Studio 2015

When I switch Unity build settings to target Windows Store application and try to build project I get errors from compiler, but they are unreadable, a lot of text displayed by question  marks. The same is in Editor.log file. It looks like this:

```
-----CompilerOutput:-stdout--exitcode: 1--compilationhadfailure: True--outfile: Temp/Assembly-CSharp.dll

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.0079.0

for C# 5

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

*** SOME OUTPUT HERE ***

Assets\AmplifyMotion\Plugins\WorkerThreadPool.cs(113,3): error CS0433: ��� "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" ���������� ��� � "c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\System.Threading.Tasks.dll", ⠪ � � "c:\Users\dmitr\Documents\projects\JELLIES 2\Assets\Parse\Parse.Unity.dll"

*** AND SO ON ***
```

Here is how does this look in Unity editor:
[image]

How could it be solved? Because I can't even read what is wrong to fix for Windows Store target.

Comment: Try switching between Mono and Net Core and Net Core Partially.

Comment: @Rafal I tried, but it's output is unreadable too and some more compiler errors appeared in console. Also Unity crashes after some seconds after the end of the compilation.

Comment: I switched Windows GUI to English and now compiler's output is readable in English. It could be used as workaround, but user interface of whole OS will be in English. I suppose that Microsoft C# compiler uses system language for output and Unity interprets it's encoding incorrectly. Maybe is it possible to specify compiler locale as additional parameter somewhere in Unity?

Comment: Unity3D 5.3.2f1 does not have such problem